# java output notepad file contains no data

Tags: java

This code reads colors from a file and then writes to notepad.
 It works fine except that I get one long column of numbers .
When I try changing the code to get multicolumns the output file is empty.
If there are too many columns does it accept no data?
thnks Dave

```
package color1;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class color1 {

        public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
        try {
            //read image file
            File file1 = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\project\\quh2.jpg");
            BufferedImage image1 = ImageIO.read(file1);

            int h=image1.getHeight();

            int w=image1.getWidth();

            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\project\\pixellog1.txt");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);

            out.write(""+h+","+w);

            for (int x=250; x<800; x=x+10) {

               for (int y=0; y<500; y=y+10){
                  int c = image1.getRGB(x,y);
                  Color color = new Color(c);
                  float  p = color.getRed();

                   out.newLine();
                   out.write(""+p);

                }
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}t of numbers
```

Comment: You should make sure you call 'flush' and 'close' on `out` to ensure the buffer is flushed and written the file.

Comment: Not related to question, but you do not require the "" in `out.write(""+p);` Just `out.write(p);` will work for primitives. For Objects if you see something like "Float@534ab" you should use the `.toString()` or `String.parse(p)` functions.

Comment: @colind You should make that an answer

Comment: @MadProgrammer If I were to do anything more than comment, it would be track down and flag this a duplicate of something.

Comment: @ColinD You could do that to ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should close the resources you use.

In this case, your output file is not properly closed so the written data is never flushed to the file.

Try adding this after your outer for loop:

`out.close();`